# Setting up a custom domain with AWS Api Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to setup an API Gateway integration using a custom domain that points to an Lambda function but I'm running into some issues. A lot of the docs seem show different screens to what I now see in the console.

I've created a Lambda function and setup an API Gateway trigger. I can see the API created correctly in API Gateway with an invoke url like:

```
https://foo.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

I've then tried to add my own custom domain e.g api.example.com which, when I click on for more details, has generated an API Gateway Domain Name similar to :

```
https://bar.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

I've then setup a mapping that maps this domain name to the API with the `foo` invoke url above.

```
API                    Stage        Path         Default endpoint
MY-API                 $default     (none)       Enabled
```

I've then tried to setup a geolocation redirect in Route53. When I choose to route traffic to 'an alias to API gateway API' the console only lets me choose the `bar` domain name rather than the `foo` invoke url.

I've tried manually setting this to the `foo` domain which is accepted (it sets this up as an A record using the wizard whereas I expected it to be a CNAME). This record looks like so when using the suggested domain:

```
api.example.com A   Geolocation Europe  bar.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.
```

Either way, when I try to visit my custom domain I receive an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` message.
If I visit the `BAR` domain (the one API gateway created for my custom domain) I receive the same error.

If I visit my invoke URL this loads an actual error page (testing my lambda within the lambda console works however). I'm not sure if this is a just a red herring on the above but I thought I would add in that this is also erroring but in a different way.

I should also point out that SSL cert is created by AWS certificate manager and everything is in the same region

I appreciate there's a lot of parts of this and I've hopefully made the setup clear, but can anyone point me to how I should get my custom domain working here? I don't seem to have any logs that makes pinpointing an error clear

thanks

Comment: Have you checked this option [Define a custom domain name for API Gateway API](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-domain-name-amazon-api-gateway/) and  [Routing traffic to an Amazon API Gateway API by using your domain name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-api-gateway.html). Have you also explored option of using any reverse proxy such as nginx (with proxy_pass to AWS API Gateway)?

Comment: I didn't really want to use a reverse proxy as I thought I was simplifying my setup. I've followed those docs to the best of my knowledge and where possible used tools in the console to create resources automatically. I didn't really want to scrap everything and start again but at the moment I'm feeling like  that's my only option

Comment: After following above docs, do you configure the API mappings (API / Stage / Path)?

Comment: Yes, the only thing I didn't put in was a path and just left that as the default as shown above